Flex row not working in React Native after reading all post here
I don't know what is wrong with my code, but always shows the < Text > under the < TouchableOpacity >. I tried to change everything in the code without results, nor about others similar troubles I tried to find here. FlexDirection: row doesn't work in any case. :
const Task = (props) => {

return (
    <View style={styles.item}>

        <View styles={styles.itemLeft}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.square}></TouchableOpacity>
            <Text style={styles.itemText}>{props.text}</Text>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.circular}></View>
    </View>

)}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
item: {
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
    padding: 15,
    borderRadius: 10,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    marginBottom: 20,
},
itemLeft: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    // flexWrap: 'nowrap',
},

square: {
    width: 24,
    height: 24,
    backgroundColor: '#FAA300',
    opacity: 0.4,
    borderRadius: 5, 
    marginRight: 15,
},
itemText: {
    maxWidth: '80%',
    // minWidth: '80%',
},

circular: {
    width: 12,
    height: 12,
    borderColor: '#55BCF6',
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderRadius: 5,


},
})


Define a width for itemLeft
